# Oracle PL/SQL default value in VARRAY at the time of declaration

Tags: arrays, oracle

what is the initial value in the elements at the time of declaration for the following line of code

```
TYPE IntA IS VARRAY(100) of NUMBER;
list IntA := IntA();
```

I wanna know the default value stored in the elements of list.

Comment: What is initial value of what. You are declaring a type here. Where is the variable declaration?

Comment: @Mottor, initial value in the elements of array of number. in Java, elements are all initialized to 0 in int array, what about this situation?

Comment: You are declaring empty array here. What can be initial value in empty array in java?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov This is wrong in this case. list(1) does not exist and list is not null. list is empty array. To have value should be used EXTEND or BULK COLLECT  (which actually creates new array)

Comment: @Mottor, so what will list(1) return? is list(1) == null?

Comment: ORA-06533: Index oberhalb der Grenze   (SUBSCRIPT_BEYOND_COUNT)

Comment: @Mottor you are correct - hasty comment. Deleted it.

Comment: @Mottor, then what will list.last return? 0? or 100?

Comment: FIRST and LAST will return NULL. There is no first and last elements, because the array is empty. COUNT returns 0.

Comment: There are 3 types of collections in Oracle. Tell me for what you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding [how VARRAYs work](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS443). When you declare your type as `VARRAY(100)` you are specifying the maximum number of elements an instance of that type **can** contain, not how many it **will** contain.

In your example you are then [initialising the collection with no arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS00504):

> If the parameter list is empty, the constructor returns an empty collection.

So the collection is empty; it has zero elements (out of a maximum you have set of 100); and the `first` and `last` methods return null as they are unknown/meaningless for an empty collection.

When you add elements to the array using `extend` the new elements are also null, until you assign a value to them.

To illustrate the behaviour @Mottor has described in comments, you can use an anonymous block to manipulate an array and see what it looks like at each stage:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  type t_array is varray(100) of number;
  l_array t_array;

  procedure show_array_info(p_step pls_integer) is
  begin
    dbms_output.put('Step ' || p_step || ': ');
    if l_array is null then
      dbms_output.put_line('array has not been intialised');
      return;
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('count ' || l_array.count
      || ' first ' || nvl(to_char(l_array.first), '(null)')
      || ' last ' || nvl(to_char(l_array.last), '(null)'));
    if l_array.count = 0 then
      return;
    end if;
    for i in l_array.first..l_array.last loop
      dbms_output.put_line('  element ' || i || ': '
        || nvl(to_char(l_array(i)), '(null)'));
    end loop;
  end show_array_info;
begin
  -- array has been declared buyt not initialised
  show_array_info(1);
  -- initialisae array as empty
  l_array := t_array();
  show_array_info(2);
  -- increase number of elements by default 1; element is null
  l_array.extend;
  show_array_info(3);
  -- set value for last element
  l_array(l_array.count) := 42;
  show_array_info(4);
  -- increase number of elements by 3; new elements are null
  l_array.extend(3);
  show_array_info(5);
  -- set value for last element; others remain null
  l_array(l_array.count) := 17;
  show_array_info(6);
  -- remove last two elements; other two remain
  l_array.trim(2);
  show_array_info(7);
  -- remove all elements, leaving array empty
  l_array.trim(l_array.count);
  show_array_info(8);
--  l_array.extend(97);
end;
/
```

That produces:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Step 1: array has not been intialised
Step 2: count 0 first (null) last (null)
Step 3: count 1 first 1 last 1
  element 1: (null)
Step 4: count 1 first 1 last 1
  element 1: 42
Step 5: count 4 first 1 last 4
  element 1: 42
  element 2: (null)
  element 3: (null)
  element 4: (null)
Step 6: count 4 first 1 last 4
  element 1: 42
  element 2: (null)
  element 3: (null)
  element 4: 17
Step 7: count 2 first 1 last 2
  element 1: 42
  element 2: (null)
Step 8: count 0 first (null) last (null)
```

If you tried to refer to the first element while the collection was empty - or more generally, any element using a number greater than the current count - you would get error `ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count`. If you tried to extend the collection beyond the limit it was declare with you would get `ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit`.

Comment: thanks for clear explanation. I rarely deal with array in sql. So I got curious when i was reading up about. However, I felt that the documentation from oracle is rather vague.